# How to display image in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services

I am having problem in displaying worker image in SSRS Reports from database.

When inserting image on the report by selecting Database option in image properties the image is showing red cross mark.

How do I show worker images on MVS reports or in Report Builder?

Comment: If your image is sorted in the database in a varbinary column then it should work. Is the actual image stored or just a file location/URL?

Comment: please check my image table pic and suggest : https://ibb.co/kPyQkk

Comment: That 'appears' to be a valid image format. I've never had any issues doing what you are attempting. Can you post a screenshot of the design with any properties relating to the image.

Comment: please see the screen shot : https://ibb.co/kKjed5

Comment: First try just choosing the field name (IMAGE) from the drop down list rather than using FIRST. Also, have you made sure that the image is in the correct format (jpeg)

Comment: its seem the problem is with report builder by not showing images on preview, i have tried this in MVS and its worked fine, thanks a lot